# IValidatableObject passes validation but StringLength is Invalid

Tags: validation, c#-4.0, tdd, entity, ivalidatableobject

I have a test class with a couple tests that check to see if the entity `IsValid`. I moved to using `IValidatableObject` from having my own custom validation but I'm stuck with the correct validation technique.

**This is my Test class:**

```
[TestFixture]
public class StudentTests {
    private static Student GetContactWithContactInfo()
    {
        return new Student(new TestableContactRepository())
                            {
                                Phone = "7275551111"
                            };
    }

    private static Student GetContactWithoutContactInfo()
    {
        return new Student(new TestableContactRepository());
    }

    [Test]
    public void Student_Saving_StudentHasInfo_IsValid ()
    {
        // Arrange
        Student student = GetContactWithContactInfo();
        // Act
        student.Save();
        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(student.IsValid);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Student_Saving_StudentDoesNotHaveInfo_IsNotValid ()
    {
        // Arrange
        Student student = GetContactWithoutContactInfo();
        // Act
        student.Save();
        // Assert
        Assert.IsFalse(student.IsValid);
    }
}
```

**This is my entity:**

```
public class Student : IValidatableObject
{
    private readonly IContactRepository contactRepository;

    public Student(IContactRepository _contactRepository)
    {
        contactRepository = _contactRepository;
        Contacts = new List<Student>();
    }

    [Required]
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 10)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }


    public List<Student> Contacts { get; private set; }

    public bool IsValid { get; private set; }

    public void Save()
    {
        if (IsValidForPersistance())
        {
            IsValid = true;
            Id = contactRepository.Save();
        }
    }

    private bool IsValidForPersistance()
    {
        return Validator.TryValidateObject(this, new ValidationContext(this), null, true);
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Phone) && Contacts.All(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Phone)))
            yield return new ValidationResult("The student or at least one contact must have a phone number entered", new[] { "Phone Number" });
    }
}
```

As you can see the tests test for `IsValid` by calling the `IsValidForPersistance`. `Validate` will eventually have more validation .

The above tests all pass using this method but this test below also passes but should not.

```
[Test]
public void Student_Saving_HasContactInfoWithInvalidLength_IsNotValid()
{
    // Arrange
    Contact student = GetContactWithoutContactInfo();
    student.Phone = "string";

    // Act
    student.Save();

    // Assert
    Assert.IsFalse(student.IsValid);
}
```

Here I'm setting my own `Phone` value of an invalid length string. I expect validation to fail because of the `StringLength` annotation set at min and max 10 characters.

Why is this passing?

**Update**
There was a problem with the custom validation, updated the code with the change. Along with the suggestion from nemesv about not having a `private` modifier on the `Phone` property it now works. I've updated all the code to working.

Comment: I'm looking into this link right now as it has a demo project. The project implements some extra helper classes that work with the Validator. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/256183/DataAnnotations-Validation-for-Beginner

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Validator.TryValidateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411772) **only checks** the `RequiredAttribute`s (and also other things like type level attributes and `IValidatableObject` implementation) by default.

If you need to validate **all the attributes** like `StringLength` etc. you need to set the `validateAllProperties` parameter of the method to `true`

```
private bool IsValidForPersistance() {
    return Validator.TryValidateObject(this, 
                                       new ValidationContext(this), 
                                       null,
                                       true /* validateAllProperties */);
}
```

Comment: I've updated my code and have the `validateAllProperties` value set to true now but I still get the same result. That same test still passes as if it is valid

Comment: You code works for me with `validateAllProperties = true`. Only one thing I've change in your Phone property `public string Phone { private get; set; }` I've made the get public so it should be `public string Phone { get; set; }`